# Burning a microcontroller's peripheral. is it possible?

Tags: microcontroller, damage, peripheral

Have you came across with a microcontroller by chance which a/two/... peripheral(s) of the microcontroller didn't work? or at first a peripheral of your MCU was working but now it doesn't? I mean could it be possible that a/two/... peripheral(s) of a microcontroller burn out(while other parts of the MCU work)?

Sometimes we hear from some users that when a part/peripheral of an MCU doesn't work, they say "you have damaged that peripheral/part of the MCU". is this remark correct? I'm not a beginner but after several years I'm curious to know it.

Comment: I am really not sure what you are asking here. Of course parts of a micro can be damaged.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thank you for answer. What part isn't clear? feel free to ask your questions.

Comment: Are you talking about an entire peripheral block? It is possible a single pin being damaged can do this, but these can often be configured on different pins; do you have a specific question?

Comment: This isn't a clear question, what kind of peripheral? This is a broad question.

Comment: He's asking if part of an MCU can be busted while it still appears to be functional otherwise -- yes.

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks. no more question. I just wanted to know it. and also some MCUs doesn't support such a feature to remap your pins. although my STM32 has such ability. :)

Comment: @laptop2d What? really no matter what kind of peripheral we are talking about. what's the point of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one occasion, I have damaged ADC in a PIC with ESD. The damaged ADC would give readings that would be off by a factor of 2 to 3. The rest of the PIC performed nominally, as far as I could tell. This didn't happen just once, I have damaged several units in the same way during that project. Then I found the problem with my ESD setup, fixed it, the damage stopped occurring.

Answer (score 3):

The damage comes from the outside through the pin(s). Usually, the circuitry close to the pin will get damaged first and then all peripherals that can be assigned to this pin will stop working. If pin functions are remappable, like in PIC24 and friends, you can move your peripheral to the pin that is not yet damaged.